# mv: cannot stat '*.dds': No such file or directory

Tags: bash, mv

I'm using two short bash scripts for renaming all *.dds files in all directories.

The first one:

```
#!/bin/bash
j=39;
for i in *.dds;
do let j+=1;
mv $i 0150$j.dds;
done
```

The second one:

```
CURDIR=`pwd`
for d in $(find . -type d);
do
    cd $CURDIR/"$d"
    $CURDIR/3_rename.sh
done
```

I'm running the second one and obtain:

```
mv: cannot stat '*.dds': No such file or directory
```

But *.dds files are renamed correctly. I would like to understand my mistake which leads to the error.

Comment: You can try to debug your script by running it using `bash -x script.sh`, and see what it actually does.

Comment: Is the first script one the `3_rename.sh` that the second one runs? If so, that's what I'd expect to happen if it runs in a directory with no .dds files. BTW, there are some situations where the first script will accidentally delete files due to naming conflicts (especially if it's run multiple times in a directory with a large number of .dds files). You should use `mv -i` or `mv -n` for mass renames like this to prevent accidents.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yes, the first script is `3_rename.sh` and I run it in a directory with no .dds files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your rename script, the `*.dds` glob expands to the file names in the current directory that end with a .dds extension: 1.dds, 2.dds and so on.

The problem here is a directory that does not have any files ending with a .dds extension, so there is nothing for the glob to match. In this scenario, the default behaviour of `bash` is to return the literal string '*.dds'. This gets passed on to the `mv` command, which prints an error as no such file exists.

The shell option 'nullglob' can adjust this behaviour. With 'nullglob' turned on, non-matching globs will disappear instead of returning the literal string. With zero arguments, the `for` loop will skip the empty directory.

You can turn on 'nullglob' just before your loop:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *.dds;
...
```

More details and examples are available here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob . Do note the warning and portability sub-sections, as they highlight some of the concerns in using 'nullglob'.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I run it in a directory with no .dds files. .dds files are only in subdirectories.